# Last column in a table not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a pretty crazy code that make it possible to click and expand rows in a dynamic table. My problem is that I need to make the last column in the table not clickable, and I have no idea how to do that. I have searched the internet and tried different things, but nothing seems to help.

This is my table:

```
<table id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                    </tr>
           {{#each companies}}

                   <tr class="record">
                       <td>
                          {{this.name}}
                       </td>
                       <td>
                          {{this.type}}
                      </td>
                      <td id="details">
                          <img style="height: 20px; width: 20px" src="img/arrow_right.png">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
         {{/each}}
  </table>
```

I want to make that last column (ID = "details") not clickable.

This is my crazy click event:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr.record", function () {
            var rowIndex = this.rowIndex,
                    services = null;
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/relation",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response[rowIndex - 1].relationStats) {
                        services = response[rowIndex - 1].relationStats.PROVIDES_SERVICE;
                    }

                    if (services > 0 && $(self).hasClass('record active')) {
                        console.log("CLOSING");
                        $(self.nextSibling).remove();
                        $(self).removeClass('active');

                    } else if (services > 0) {
                        console.log("OPENING");
                        var openDetails = $('<tr/>').addClass('openDetails').insertAfter(self);
                        $(self).addClass('active');
                        var td = $('<td/>').addClass('td').appendTo(openDetails);
                        $('<p/>').html("Provides service(s):&nbsp").appendTo(td);
                        $('<td/>').html(services).appendTo(openDetails);

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of registering the click handler to `tr` use `td` and filter out the last-child

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "td:not(:last-child)", function () {
    var self = $(this).closest('tr').get(0), rowIndex = self.rowIndex,
        services = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/relation",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response[rowIndex - 1].relationStats) {
                services = response[rowIndex - 1].relationStats.PROVIDES_SERVICE;
            }

            if (services > 0 && $(self).hasClass('record active')) {
                console.log("CLOSING");
                $(self.nextSibling).remove();
                $(self).removeClass('active');

            } else if (services > 0) {
                console.log("OPENING");
                var openDetails = $('<tr/>').addClass('openDetails').insertAfter(self);
                $(self).addClass('active');
                var td = $('<td/>').addClass('td').appendTo(openDetails);
                $('<p/>').html("Provides service(s):&nbsp").appendTo(td);
                $('<td/>').html(services).appendTo(openDetails);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have already tried that, doesn't work. I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'relationStats' of undefined "

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "#details", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "td:not(:last)", function () {.....}
```

instead of `not(:last-child)`,if the situation is:

```
<tr>
   <td>....</td>
   <td>....</td>
   <td class="not record">....</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>....</td>
   <td>....</td>
   <td class="record">....</td>
</tr>
```

reference [last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/),[last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)